# how to delete single recodrs from multiple row records like gridview in jsp page

Tags: java, javascript, jsp

I am trying to edit and delete a single record from multiple records.Here below is my sample record displaying on jsp page,

[image]

I can edit the record for each row easily using below code,

```
  <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
        pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
         <%@ page import="java.util.List" %>
          <%@ page import="java.util.Iterator" %>

     <%@page import="java.sql.ResultSet"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Insert title here</title>
    <script src="jquery1.11.0.min.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>

        <script type="text/javascript">


                function editRecording(task_id) {
                    //alert(task_id)

                            url = "EditRecord";
                            window.location="/RTTSchecking/"+url+"?task_id="+task_id;

                    }


        </script>

  <table align="center" border="1px" width="80%"  >
    <thead>
        <tr>
        <th>User_Id</th>
        <th>Class</th>
        <th>Subject</th>
        <th>Chapter</th>
        <th>Planned_Features</th>
        <th>Planned_Date</th>

    </thead>


            <%Iterator itr;%>       
            <%List data = (List) request.getAttribute("TaskData");

            for(itr = data.iterator(); itr.hasNext();)
            {
                %>
                <tr>
                <% String s = (String) itr.next(); 
                %>
                <td style="background-color: yellow;">
                <input type="text" name="tid" value="<%=s %>"></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="tid" value="<%=itr.next() %>"></td>

                <td><%=itr.next() %></td>
                <td><%=itr.next() %></td>
                <td><%=itr.next() %></td>
                <td><%=itr.next() %></td>


                <td><input type="button"  value="edit" name="<%=s%>" onclick="editRecording(this.name);"></td> 
             <td><input type="button"  value="delete" name="<%=s%>" onclick="deleteRecording(this.name);"></td> 



                <% } %>



                </tr>

                </table>


    </body>
    </html>
```

**EditREcord(servlet):**

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        try {

            String a=request.getParameter("task_id");

        convty = new Connectivity();
        con = convty.setConnection();
        st = con.createStatement();
        query = "select * from task_table where task_id='"+a+"'";
        rset = convty.getResultSet(query, con);


        }
        catch(Exception e) {

        }
        finally {
            request.setAttribute("EditData", rset);
            RequestDispatcher dd= request.getRequestDispatcher("editdata.jsp");
            dd.forward(request, response);
            out.close();
            //out.println(""+tid);
        }

    }
```

Above code working fine.But my problem is, i want to delete record based on User_id, Class, Subject, Chapter and Planned_Date so how can i get these values from single row (which want to delete row)?

how to achive this below code?,

```
  <script type="text/javascript">


                        function deleteRecording(User_id,Class,Subject,Chapter,Date) {
                            //alert(task_id,Class,Subject,Chapter,Date)

                                    url = "EditRecord";
                                    window.location="/RTTSchecking/"+url+"?user_id="+User_id+"&Tclass="+Class+"&subject="+Subject+"&chapter="+Chapter+"&date="+Date;

                </script>
```

once if i achieved above code then i can easily delete selected single record from multiple rows using below code,

```
try {

                String uid=request.getParameter("user_id");
String class=request.getParameter("Tclass");
String sub=request.getParameter("subject");
String chap=request.getParameter("chapter");
String date=request.getParameter("date");

            convty = new Connectivity();
            con = convty.setConnection();
            st = con.createStatement();
            query = "delete from task_table where User_id='"+uid+"' and class='"+class+"' and subject='"+sub+"' and chapter='"+chap+"' and date='"+date+"'";
           st.executeUpdate(query);


            }
            catch(Exception e) {

            }
```

**Note :** I can do delete records using **delete from task_table where User_id='"+uid+"';**

but how to do with  **query = "delete from task_table where User_id='"+uid+"' and class='"+class+"' and subject='"+sub+"' and chapter='"+chap+"' and date='"+date+"'";**

I hope someone will help me out.

Comment: ok fine can you share your code?

Comment: sorry, deleted that comment. Since you're passing the value through URL, so you'll be doing it in the doGet action in servlet. So you've to assign the values in hidden parameter inside that <td></td> tag

Comment: why did you specified name="tid" in both the first two fields..? Maybe change it to name="uid" in first field and name="class" in second field. Finaly in onclick, pass it as like onclick="editRecording(uid,class);">

Comment: if i pass values using editRecording(uid,class,chapter,subject,date) means it always takes first row's values not selected row's values.

Comment: If your edit and delete is properly enclosed within that particular row, it'll work..

Comment: the problem is i cant pass the textbox's name attribute values into deleteRecording(uid,class,subject,date).there is error when i do this way

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63745/discussion-between-manivasagam-and-krnaveen14).

Comment: I feel as if it's worth nothing that you are using TONS Of bad practices in your code, you should **NEVER** pass raw get input to a database without [`PreparedStatements`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html), i could literally sumbit a request where the uid was `' DROP TABLE task_table; -- ` and then your applications is dead, please please PLEASE use preparedstatements, another thing, using scriptlets inside of your jsp is generally bad practice, doing it in [JSTL](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info) would be much better.

Answer (score 0):

Once you delete data from database that means it's deleted.

You just need to reload that page again on click of delete.

Comment: He doesn't meant that. He asked on how to pass the values of Class,Subject,Chapter,Date to the code which gets the data from webpage.

Comment: i understand but my problem is how to get that all values when click on delete button?

Answer (score 0):

I hope you've found the solution to your problem by now.  But in case you haven't, I ran into the same problem today, and after many experiments, I came up with the following syntax for deleting a row using multiple criteria:

```
  " DELETE FROM table_name WHERE " +
  " first_db_field_name = '" + matching_variable_name + "'" +
  " and next_db_field_name = '" + next_matching_variable_name + "'" +
  " and last_db_field_name = '" + last_matching_variable_name + "'";
```